# What is the solution for "Server Execution Failed" in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, networking

I cannot connect to any network using Windows Vista. When I go to the Network tray icon, it says "Server Execution Failed".

This is not my computer, but for the record, it does not have AIM installed. I have heard this is a common problem.

Comment: Guess you'll have to either execute the server yourself, or hire a hitman! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution was to reinstall Windows. I had to do it anyway, and there was no other valid suggestions. For the time being, this is the standing answer.

Please do not vote down. I know this is an extremely inefficient answer and not at all the actual best solution, but I am putting an answer up to accept. If you have a better answer, by all means, post it!